# Picking which ocaml module to use with command line parameter

Tags: module, functional-programming, ocaml

In my code I've `module M = Implementation1` and then I reference `M`, instead of `Implementation1`. The problem is, I've to recompile my program to change `Implementation1` to `Implementation2`. I'd like to control which implementation to use from with a command line parameter. Is that possible?

Is the situation simpler, when all implementations share signature?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Are you dealing with only two implementations known statically, in which case you should look for [first class modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc81), or with implementations that may be added later in which case you need to look for [dynamic linking](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Dynlink.html).

Comment: I've two implementations known statically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since both implementation are known statically you can use [first class modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc81). There are quite a few different possibilities on how to structure your program, here's one that minimizes toplevel reference cells and toplevel effectful statements:

```
module type M = sig
  val test : unit -> unit
end

module M1 : M = struct
  let test () = Printf.printf "Implementation 1\n%!" 
end

module M2 : M = struct
  let test () = Printf.printf "Implementation 2\n%!"
end

let test m = 
  let module M = (val m : M) in 
  (* If other modules of your program depend on the implementation of 
     M, functorize them over sig M and instantiate them with M here. *)
  M.test ()

let main () = 
  let exec = Filename.basename Sys.executable_name in 
  let usage = Printf.sprintf
      "Usage: %s [OPTION]...\n\
       Program synopsis.\n\
       Options:" exec 
  in
  let m = ref (module M1 : M) in
  let options = [
    "-m1", Arg.Unit (fun () -> m := (module M1 : M)), 
    " Use implementation 1 (default)"; 
    "-m2", Arg.Unit (fun () -> m := (module M2 : M)),
    " Use implementation 2"; ]
  in
  let anon _ = raise (Arg.Bad "no positional argument supported") in 
  Arg.parse (Arg.align options) anon usage; 
  test !m

let () = main ()
```

Answer (score 2):

For most versions of OCaml you can do this with camlp4.

```
IFDEF USE_IMP1 THEN
  module M = Implementation1
ELSE
  module M = Implementation2
END
```

Then passing the pre-processing options like the following will choose the correct one to incorporate in the build.

```
-pp "camlp4of -UUSE_IMP1" //to undefine USE_IMP1
-pp "camlp4of -DUSE_IMP1" //to define USE_IMP2
```

For versions of OCaml >= 4.00.0 you can use the First-Class modules and an expression like,

```
module Choose = (val (if use_impl1 then (module Impl_1) else (module Impl_2)) : IMP)
```

to use an if statement to choose the module as determined by the `use_impl1` value.