# OCaml conditional file reading

Tags: file-io, ocaml, conditional-statements

I want to do the command #use "a.ml" conditionally
i.e., in 'if statement' as shown below...

`let funs = function (true) -> #use "1.ml"

                   | (false)-> #use "2.ml";;`

is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

The `#use` directive is part of the interpretive environment (REPL) of the OCaml toplevel. It's not a construct of the OCaml language itself. So your example code makes no sense as an OCaml program.

However, it's pretty clear what you want to do: you want to choose between two implementations of a set of functions (i.e., two modules) at runtime.

This is what first-class modules are for. See this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093791/picking-which-ocaml-module-to-use-with-command-line-parameter/21104684#21104684).